# Programming ATtiny85 with Arduino-IDE and an 8MHz external oscillator

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, attiny85, arduino-as-isp

I have a *digispark* ATtiny85 development board and I am using the Arduino IDE to program it along with the Arduino UNO as my hardware programmer.

I have successfully burned the fuses for both the internal 1 and 8 MHz RC oscillators using the *original* Arduino as ISP sketch (you'll understand why I said *original* in a moment), but as my application needs precise timing, I would like to use an external oscillator, however, every time I tried to burn/program the bootloader/fuses using the Arduino IDE and using the *original* Arduino as ISP, the avrdude spits the infamous (Yikes).
I searched online and found an *updated* version of the Arduino as ISP sketch, which is supposed to an updated version, it has only one downside, which is, it can't do anything other than burn/program the bootloader/fuses, meaning that it can't be used to program the ATtiny85 like the *original* Arduino as ISP could do.

So without hesitating, I tested it to burn/program the bootloader/fuses for the internal 1 and 8 MHz RC oscillators, and it worked perfectly, and as expected, it fails to upload the code.
But the *original* Arduino as ISP successfully uploaded the code.
When I tried to burn/program the bootloader/fuses for the *external* 8MHz crystal oscillator using the *updated* Arduino as ISP, it worked flawlessly... until I noticed that the ordinary Arduino as ISP can not upload the code anymore and I am presented with the infamous (Yikes!) error.

Let me elaborate the difference in the *connections* between the two sketches.
The updated Arduino as ISP generates a clock signal on pin #9, which connects to the CLKI of the ATtiny85 (AKA Pin #2 "PB3"), while the *original* Arduino as ISP does not utilize this pin at all.

I found the updated Arduino as ISP on the *electronics stack exchange* forum, but unfortunately I lost the link to the question which contained why is this updated Arduino as ISP is better.
I can provide both codes though if someone needs them.

I have my crystal connected in both cases, burning/programming the bootloader/fuses and while trying to upload my code.

This is the infamous (Yikes!) error which I was talking about.
[image]

This is my current wiring.
[image]
Please note that I connect pin #9 to the CLKI of the ATtiny85 (AKA Pin #2 "PB3"), only when I am using the *updated* Arduino as ISP.

This is the *actual* wiring.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

My two questions are:

1. How could I burn/program the bootloader/fuses of the ATtiny85 to use an external oscillator of 8MHz or 16 MHz?
2. How could I upload my application code after burning/programming the bootloader/fuses?

I hope the answers elaborate how the connections would differ, if it would.

Thank a lot in advance.

Comment: It may just be because I'm tired, but: You programmed the fuses for use with a crystal.  Did you not attach a crystal?

Comment: @timemage, good comment, I forgot to mention that I have my crystal *connected* in both cases, burning/programming the bootloader/fuses *and* while trying to upload my code.

Comment: Can you show how this is wired?

Comment: @timemage, yes, allow me 5 minutes to upload a proper image please.

Comment: @timemage, post edited.

Comment: I was sort of looking for a picture of the actual wiring.  But, your diagram does raise the question: Do you not have any load capacitors?

Comment: @timemage, no problem I can upload a picture of the actual wiring, sorry for the misunderstanding.
But to answer your question, if by load capacitors you mean the capacitors connected between the crystal pins and ground, no I have both of them disconnected.
But if you mean the decoupling capacitors connected between VCC and GND, yes I do have these connected, one 0.1uF to be exact.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122669/discussion-between-timemage-and-abd-alrahman-muhammad).

Comment: @jsotola, I am sorry, I only wanted to reach more people in different fields.
That post is now deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [Digispark Schematic](https://s3.amazonaws.com/digispark/DigisparkSchematicFinal.pdf) you'll see resistors and Zener diodes attached to XTAL1 and XTAL2:
[image: Digispark Schematic with circuitry connected to XTAL1 and XTAL2 pins highlighted.]

These are for the USB D+ and D- signals that the Digispark bit-bangs.  I deeply suspect that the crystal is just not going to resonate with these parts connected.

To get back to a working Digispark you'll probably have to inject signal onto XTAL1 again and reprogram the fuses to internal OSC.

Comment: Thank you, I am glad you asked for actual wiring.
Can I "in theory" remove the resistors R1 and R2 so I can test this out?
The end-user project will not be using a digispark, but a bare-metal ATtiny85 on a PCB.

Comment: Yes, that should allow you to use an external crystal.  Although it will no longer bit-bang USB, but I suspect you understand that.

Comment: Yes, I do understand, thank you very much for your time.
I will try what I have said and get back to you if you please.

Thank you.

Comment: It may be a number of hours before I see any update or respond to it.

Comment: No problem at all, take your time.

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot.
Words can't express it really.

Comment: It might have been easier to use a bare ATTiny85 DIL package and a 5V linear voltage regulator, you don't seem to be using much else on the Digispark. The old "Arduino as ISP" sketch supported three diagnostic LEDs which were useful. AVR programmers can be quite inexpensive - e.g. I like the [Pololu USB AVR programmer](https://coolcomponents.co.uk/products/pololu-usb-avr-programmer-v2-1) ([another](https://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/pololu-usb-avr-prog-v2))